# Como salvar sessão php no MongoDB e recuperar dados em NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

Estou a correr um servidor em `php` e outro em `nodejs` tentando buscar uma autenticação simples visto que toda sessão corre em `php` e `nodejs` simplesmente processa alguns eventos porém, e necessário autenticação como posso fazer com MongoDB (drive php)?

Tentei com **memcache** (php e node) porém não obtive sucesso uma vez que **memcache dll** para `php7` ainda esta em status **dev** (desenvolvimento).

Comment: Presumo que estás a correr PHP e Node na mesma máquina com ambos a aceder ao MongoDB, certo? Podes clarificar isso e também corrigir alguns erros ortográficos? Pergunta interessante, `+1`.

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso. O projeto em si é um website em php e funcionalidades como chat, plugins e apps em nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Em lugar de sessão, pode usar o padrão [JWT](https://jwt.io/) de tokens, já vai encontrar material pronto em diversas linguagens.

Por exemplo, no login você pode gerar o token, e verificá-lo em outra máquina, sem precisar de acesso ao banco. Isso é perfeito para escalabilidade, pois diversos servidores podem validar o token sem conversar entre si. Só é necessário que os dois utilizem a mesma chave.

- Documentação, playground e exemplos: https://jwt.io/
- Implementação em NodeJS: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken
- Implementação em PHP: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

O token JWT pode conter informação como o ID do usuário, e também tem uma data de expiração, que será respeitada na hora da validação.

Comment: Usava jwt com socket.io porém agora estou a usar express4 com passport-local e espress-session e a idea não seria mais passar parâmetros como id de usuário ou sessão via query-string e sim um token criado em php e salvo (com php) no banco MongoDB e recuperar isto (usando o token). Node receberia apenas o token via query-string e buscaria a referencia em MongoDB (com mongodb ou mongoose) para buscar esta session e usar em node (express-session).